# I want to know, where JVM try to get resources(File Handler..) from OS and complete file write operation

Tags: java

In java every where we use classes that implement InputStream/OutputStream. I want to know, where JVM try to get resources(File Handler....) from OS and complete those operations? Is JVM take help of rt.jar to communicate OS?

In C/C++ we have libraries that will help to make system call. So What about Java.

Answer (score 0):

In order to work with the native(OS) IO call, JVM calls C/C++ library deployed in the form of **.dll** files in case of Window or **.so** file in case of linux using **JNI (Java Native Interface)**.